# mysql get last 2 records of table with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables (order , camp , user) as bellow values,

```
order_table
ID    camp_id       orderDate       message
1       1           2015-01-01      ok
2       1           2015-02-01      ok
3       2           2015-03-01      not ok
4       3           2015-01-01      not ok
5       1           2015-04-01      not ok
6       2           2015-01-01      ok
7       3           2015-07-01      not ok

camp_table
camp_id camp_uid     camp name
1       10             first camp
2       11             second camp
3       12             third camp
4       10             forth camp

user_table
uid    uname
10      abc
11      xyz
12      wrt
```

i want to have result as bellow

```
uname,camp name,message
```

for last 2 records of each user from order_table for **today** order **by orderDate**

I want to join these tables to have **uname** from **user_table** and **camp nam**e from **camp_table** and **message** from **order_table**.
for **today** order **by orderDate**
Thanks

Comment: Please edit and explain your question in more detail.

Comment: you want to have a last 2 records from the order tale only and you want us joins  ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u.uname,
    ct.camp_name,
    ot.message
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            order_table o1
        WHERE
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    order_table o2
                WHERE
                    o1.camp_id = o2.camp_id
                AND o2.ID >= o1.ID
            ) <= 2
    ) ot
INNER JOIN camp_table ct ON ct.camp_id = ot.camp_id
INNER JOIN user_table u ON ct.camp_uid = u.uid
ORDER BY
    u.uname
```

Comment: Hello, this is endless query and mysql stuck

Comment: it works on my system, with the database values in your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select
ct.camp_name,
ut.uname,
ot.message FROM order_table as ot
LEFT JOIN camp_table as ct on ot.camp_id = ct.camp_id
LEFT JOIN user_table as ut on ct.camp_uid = ut.uid
order by ot.id desc
limit 2
```

Comment: thanks for reply No its not what i want, I want to have 2 records of each customer but today date. this is only showing 2 last records

Answer (score 1):

Order By Date and join both table.

```
  Select t1.camp_name, t2.uname,t3.message FROM order_table as t3
    LEFT JOIN camp_table as t1 on t3.camp_id = t1.camp_id
    LEFT JOIN user_table as t2 on t1.camp_uid = t2.uid
    order by t3.orderDate desc
    limit 2
```